# MongoDB find() not filtering by string

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am currently trying to retrieve certain objects from a mongoDB database using Mongoose.
For some reason I cant filter by the field "provider" that i assigned to my object, but i can filter by the "date" field.

This works perfectly:

```
const logs = await ActionLog.find({ date:{ $gt: initialDate, $lt: finishDate}});

if(logs.length == 0){
     res.status(204);
     res.json({message:"No matches for this search"});
 }else
     res.send(logs);
```

but this doesn't, it just brings me all of the elements saved:

```
const logs = await ActionLog.find({ provider:"example" } );
```

Some of the elements have the field "provider" and some of them don't, but none of them has provider:"example"

```
[
{
    "_id": "6374768bd302cd09838d4c67",
    "module": "event approval",
    "date": "2022-11-16T05:35:07.252Z",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "637476aad302cd09838d4c69",
    "module": "event update",
    "date": "2022-11-16T05:35:38.798Z",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "6374768bd302cd09838d4c11",
    "module": "sale",
    "provider": "prueba",
    "date": "2022-11-20T05:35:07.252Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

]

Comment: Please don't upload [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3082296). They can't be copied to reproduce the issue, they aren't searchable for future readers and they are harder to read than text. Please post the actual code **as text**.

Comment: Are you able to provide a sample of the returned document that does not match the query?
And perhaps the _actual_  query? Not one where the string is example?

Comment: @SelloMkantjwa done. Thats -for now- the actual query. In the future i will change "example" for a variable that contains the actual name of the provider. Nonetheless i think that is not important in order to fix my problem, right? It should work no matter what the string is, or am I missing something?

Comment: What happens when you provide a valid filter like:  `{ provider:"prueba" }`

Comment: @adiga it's the same, it brings me all of the elements

Comment: Is "provider" on your mongoose model? I havent use mongoose in a while but I think I recall that for it to query on a field it must actually be on your model. I might be remembering this wrong though.

Comment: @SelloMkantjwa that was it, thanks! I thougth i had added it but i seems like i forgot.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was my model didn't have "provider" in it.

> Blockquote s "provider" on your mongoose model? I havent use mongoose in a while but I think I recall that for it to query on a field it must actually be on your model. I might be remembering this wrong though. –
> Sello Mkantjwa

Once i added "provider" to the model it worked.